# Concentrated area of sight seeing opportunities in Bangkok, Thailand?

Tags: sightseeing, thailand, bangkok

My wife and I will be flying into Bangkok and we want to get the most out of our two night stay. Where would be an ideal area of the city that we should be looking for a hotel where we are in close proximity to a lot of the cultural experiences that Bangkok has to offer? We're not really looking for "touristy" things like souvenir shops, but more like a concentrated amount of historical sites to see. Like I said, unfortunately, we won't have a whole like of time to spend there, so any long trips outside of the city will not work for us.

Are there specific areas we should avoid, as in "tourist trap?"

Comment: As to your side question, [Khao San Road](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khaosan_Road) is kind of a "backpacker tourist trap". But instead of avoiding it completely, I suggest you pay a visit, just to broaden your impressions of Bangkok. Locals told me (2011) that it has become a somewhat hip area for Thais too, for bars & nightlife.

Comment: I like it to stay somewhere between samsen road soi 1 and soi 5. It's right by the river (for boat transfer) and a bus station on samsen road which both connect to skytrain etc. It has many budget accommodation and is close enough to khao san road to walk there. At least for me..perfect.

Answer (score 8):

Bangkok is rather spread out, but a good location would be somewhere along Sukhumvit. There's a lot of activity there, and you're close to the skytrain.

But it's by no means the only location that works. Being close to the river is nice too, as is being smack in the middle of the commercial center, close to to the excellent Bangkok Art and Culture centre.

In the end, the best location depends on what you want to see and do, and there's a lot of that in Bankgok. But, Bangkok having a lot to offer in many places, in the end it also doesn't matter too much where you're based anyway.
Perhaps the only thing to keep in the back of your mind is to find a place that's close to either the metro or the skytrain, as this will make your getting around significantly easier.

Comment: That is fantastic information to keep in mind. We fly in very late (1am) so we figured that we might have to get a hotel closer to the airport.

Comment: Well, I suppose that depends on what you're next destination will be. I'm not sure if the skytrain will still run at that time, but taxis are affordable enough and, at that time of the day, fast. If you reach your next destination by bus or train, I would most certainly stay in town, not at the airport.